# IF template tag not working in playframework2.0

Tags: java, tags, playframework-2.0

i am trying to use if tag of playframework. 
but it is not working, what it shows is the raw #{if ... in browser. i am using play2.0. in cannot find in google if there is an update for play tags.. can someone help me out please i wonder whether it begins with @

this is the tag

```
    #{if test }
     test
    #{/if}
```

Answer (score 3):

sorry for this dumb question once again! i always forget that playframework2.0 tags are just scala tags.. now i got it by doing this:

```
 @if(alltags.isEmpty) {
     <h1>Nothing to display</h1>
    } else {
 @for(tags <- alltags) {
     <li><a>@tags</a></li>
         }
    }
```

thanks for views anyway..:D